# ASP RadioButtonList Inline Below Element

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I'm wondering if it is possible to create an ASP `RadioButtonList` where the list in inline and the radio button is below the element, a `label` or `div` for example.

I have tried

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Label1" Value="1" Selected="True"><div class="box">stuff</div></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Label2" Value="2"><div class="box">stuff</div></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Label3" Value="3"><div class="box">stuff</div></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Label4" Value="4"><div class="box">stuff</div></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Label5" Value="5"><div class="box">stuff</div></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

But the label always comes before the `div` element, whereas, I would need the `div` before the `label`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well..... it's not very customizable.  I would suggest using a `<asp:RadioButton />` with a `GroupName="YYY"` setting instead, because that would give you the control that you need, which you do not get with the list form.  The RadioButton has a TextAlign that can set the text alignment in relation to the radio button, which may be helpful to your needs, but you can't set that for the list item, only the RadioButton control.

Comment: Ok. That is what I ended up doing. I appreciate your help!